# Store output of a command in a variable without losing $? value

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm developing a bash script. I need to take the output of a command and store it in a variable, and I need to know if that command was successful.

My intention was doing this(pseudo-code):

```
var = $(myCommand)

if($? = 0){
    doThings    
}else{
    doOtherThings
}
```

The problem is that `$?` keeps the result of executing `var = $()`, not `myCommand`.

Checking the output of `myCommand` won't prove that the execution was successful.

Comment: no it doesnt. `var=$(false)` sets `$?` to 1.

Comment: If you're providing pseudocode, then nobody can verify your results.  Post some actual bash code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that $? keeps the result of executing var = $(), not myCommand.

you are wrong. `$?` keeps the result of `myCommand`. A simple test can prove it, see here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let say your command is `date +%d-%m-%Y` , it prints the current date.

```
Usage : ./script.sh
cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash
command="date +%d-%m-%Y"
read var < <($command)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "success"
else
        echo "fail"
        var="$command"
fi
echo $var
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable that keeps your `$?` before assign a variable you need type this `last_status=$(echo $?)` after that you can recall $? with typing **$last_status instead of $?**

Like that;

`echo $RANDOM`

`abc=$?`

`newVar=$(cat foo)`

`echo $abc`